# Same website on different devices?

Tags: css, html, mobile, screen

Im working on a website that im trying to make responsive.

So far , it works on desktop and mobiles phones (iphone , galaxy s4..ect)

Im having a hard time trying to make the website, when its on tablets (ipad , nexus 7 ..) look like its on a mobile phone.

My website is here - http://mk18.web44.net/index2.php

you can use http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to see what I mean. Change the setting to a mobile phone like iphone. Thats what I want it to look like on an ipad.

You can look through the css - http://mk18.web44.net/css/styles.css

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I've seen, it seems to me that you are trying a bit too hard.

In order to make it like for iphones, you have to make the media query of `@media(max-width: 768px)` with the same instructions as the `@media(max-width: 360px)`.

If that's what you want, my advice is to remove the `@media(max-width: 360px)` completely and just leave the `@media(max-width: 768px)` - the css instructions within will only be applied for devices smaller than 768px in width (this includes iphones, and other phones).

Also, you should do some clean up. Css code will be parsed from top to bottom, so css instructions without any media query (the `@media` bit) will always be applied in all devices, until there is an override. One can create as many @media queries as needed, but that doesn't mean you should.

With the right css foundation, you can accomodate most devices without media queries, using them only to reorganize content and user interface just enough so that it remains usable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that worked . I understand what you mean about cleaning up the css . At this moment in time im just trying to make everything work .